# MongoDb SUM GROUP BY WHERE

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am very new to MongoDb. I have a collection Order which has multiple documents as follows.

```
{
    "vendor": "amazon",
    "date": ISODate("2016-12-05T21:10:39.100Z"),
    "products" : [
                    {
                        "id": NumberLong(590573),
                        "totalSold": NumberLong(59),
                        "totalCost": NumberLong(7350),
                        "variations": [
                                        {
                                            "varId": NumberLong(1),
                                            "totalSoldV": NumberLong(30),
                                            "totalCostV": NumberLong(3000)
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "varId": NumberLong(2),
                                            "totalSoldV": NumberLong(29),
                                            "totalCostV": NumberLong(4350)
                                        }, 
                        ] 
                    }
    ]
}
```

So what I am trying to achieve is for a particular `product.id` I want to calculate `sum(totalSold)` and `sum(totalCost)` group by `date`. I have been playing around with aggregate but haven't been able to do so.

Comment: what do you mean group by date?

Comment: @SergiuZaharie Each document has a field date. There will be multiple documents with the same date value.

Comment: you mean the same day? check my answer see if suits you.

Comment: Actually same minute :)

Comment: Also this is going to give me the sum for all products. How do I get the sum for a particular product id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$products"},
    {$match: {"products.id":NumberLong(590573) }}, 
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          year : { "$year" : "$date" },        
          month : { "$month" : "$date" },        
          day : { "$dayOfMonth" : "$date" },
          hour : { "$hour" : "$date" },
          minute : { "$minute" : "$date" },
        }, 
      sumTotalSold: {$sum: "$products.totalSold"}, sumTotalCost: {$sum: "$products.totalCost"}
    }
  }
]).pretty();
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2016,
        "month" : 12,
        "day" : 5,
        "hour" : 21,
        "minute" : 10
    },
    "sumTotalSold" : NumberLong(79),
    "sumTotalCost" : NumberLong(9850)
}
```